# Json Query not displaying correctly in MCV

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to pass data from a controller to a view to display a pie Chart.   But instead of a Pie Chart the webpage is only displaying the string as shown below. How can I get this to show the Pie Chart and not the string

[image]

```
        Controller Code
    c#
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(Result(), "text/plain",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View Code

```html
     
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8; charset = utf - 8",
                 cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
               
                
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    google.charts.load('current', {
                        'packages': ['corechart']
                    });
                    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                        drawChart(result);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

        function drawChart(result) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Marks Obtained');
            var dataArray = [];

            $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
                dataArray.push([obj.stdName, obj.marksObtained]);
            });
            data.addRows(dataArray);

            var columnChartOptions = {
                title: "Students Performance",
                width: 1000,
                height: 400,
                bar: { groupWidth: "20%" },
            };

            var columnChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document
                .getElementById('piechart_div'));

            columnChart.draw(data, columnChartOptions);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="piechart_div"></div>
```

The strange thing is that I downloaded an example, which works fine, and I set up a new MCV project and added the code exactly the same, but my project shows the string, while the project I downloaded will display the pie chart with no problems.  I am really confused as to why this is happening

Comment: Try to remove *contentType*-param with value *text/plain* to be used the default value *application/json*: "*return Json(Result(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);*"

Comment: I had that originally, but this did not work.. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why *ActionResult Index()* does return json? It should return View with markup, but json-Action should use another endpoint, for example *ActionResult GetChartContent()*.

Comment: I have change Index to return view and created and endpoint ActionResult Chart() and it still showing the string?  been at this all day today

Comment: If I were you I would make sure that page is rendered correctly on static data: for that need to comment out *$.ajax(..)*-call, manually call *drawChart* from *document.ready()* with static data - *drawChart(..data required for chart..)*